# Why isn't my click listener working for a dynamically populated grid view in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, onclicklistener

How to set an on item click event listener for a grid view that is dynamically being populated?

I have set the click listener for the gridView items. They are clickable in the xml file. However the click action is not triggered. I have tried to set the onclick listener in the onCreate method and also in the display drinks method. None of that worked. using setOnClickListener is giving the same result.

It seems like the click listener might not be properly attached or initialized. Is there a specific place or method where I should set the listener to ensure that it's working correctly? Maybe the issue lies in the fact that the GridView is being dynamically populated. Could that be causing the problem?

How can I solve this issue?

```
class DrinkAdapter(private val drinks: List<Drink>) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return drinks.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return drinks[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_item_drink, parent, false)

        val drink = drinks[position]

        val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.drinkImage)
        val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.drinkName)


        imageView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val width = imageView.width
            val height = imageView.height

            GlideApp.with(imageView)
                .load(drink.getImageUrl())
                .override(width, height)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
                .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                .into(imageView)
        }

        textView.text = drink.name

        return view
    }


}


class BrowseDrinksActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var gridView: GridView
    private lateinit var drinks: List<Drink>

    private val apiService: BrowseApiService by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(BrowseApiService::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.browse_drinks)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView)
        gridView.onItemClickListener =
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                val drink = drinks[position]
                showDrinkDetails(drink)
            }

        fetchDrinks()
    }

    private fun fetchDrinks() {
        val call: Call<List<Drink>> = apiService.getDrinks()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Drink>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Drink>>, response: Response<List<Drink>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    drinks = response.body() ?: emptyList()
                    displayDrinks(drinks)
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch drinks: ${response.code()}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Drink>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch drinks", t)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun displayDrinks(drinks: List<Drink>) {
        val adapter = DrinkAdapter(drinks)

    }

    private fun showDrinkDetails(drink: Drink) {
        val intent = Intent(this, DrinkDetailsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(DrinkDetailsActivity.EXTRA_DRINK, drink)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed()
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "BrowseDrinksActivity"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a separate interface let's say

```
interface DrinkListeners {
    fun onDrinkClicked(drink: Drink)
}
```

Change the constructor of the DrinkAdapter in the following manner:

```
class DrinkAdapter(private val drinks: List<Drink>, private val listeners: DrinkListeners) : BaseAdapter()
```

Now use this `listeners` whenever a click happens say for example:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener {
    listeners.onDrinkClicked(drinks[position])
}
```

Change the class signature

```
class BrowseDrinksActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DrinkListeners
```

Finally in the same class override the function:

```
 override fun onDrinkClicked(drink: Drink) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
```